# Powershell: Getting Error Messages about finding a user in a CSV file

Tags: powershell

[image]

I am trying to pull data from a CSV file using the code below to populate my ActiveDirectory.
I am getting "Bad syntax" for New-ADUser and "cannot find object with identity 'msteere' under 'DC=example, DC=local". msteere is a username from the CSV file and the DC part is the OUpath.

I have tried to delete the $name portion of my code but then it requires me to input their names individually and still doesn't work. I need to make this code run error free.

**The CSV file example is this:**

Firstname,Lastname,Username,OUPath,Office,maildomain,Title,Department,Password
Mike,Smith,msmith,"OU=Cincinnati, DC=example, DC=local",Cincinnati,example.local,Manager,IT,pa$$w0rd

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You should read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) specifically the Do Not post images of code.  However, I did notice you've not declared `$name` on line 7. A Sample of the CSV would also help.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how to copy Powershell code from a virtual server. The CSV looks like this: Mike, Smith, msmith, "OU=Cincinnati, DC=example, DC=local", Cincinnati, example.local, manager, marketing, pa$$w0rd

Comment: Please update the question with your csv data and include the header.

Comment: Updated with CSV and header!

Comment: Try displaying CSV with following : $Users | Format-Table

Comment: Tried the $Users | Format-Table in Line 2 and still getting the error "Cannot find an object with the identity 'HR' under: 'DC=example, DC=local'